# React JSX add min date time to datetime-local input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datetime, input

I am using React and JSX to return an input field of type "datetime-local". I want the min value to be the date we have today with the current time. I do not know how to write this however.

What I tried :

```
<input min = {new Date().toLocaleString()}  id = "date" type = "datetime-local"/>
```

which did not work and no min value is set when I choose datetime .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `min`, `max` values needs the format: `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`.

`new Date().toISOString()` returns a string which is always 24 or 27 characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively.

We can then use string manipulation methods to get the format we want, without the seconds and milliseconds bit `:ss.sssZ`, for example using [`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
 <input 
       min={new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8)}
       id="date" type="datetime-local" />
```

[image: Edit infallible-currying-0tqj9]

Comment: i had to add this split method: `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8).split('T')[0]`

Comment: When I select your option and select from the date time picker the current time, the form does not allow me to submit saying that I should choose 2 hours less. Any ideas?

Comment: @Biobrolly there is no `<form>` in my codesanbox, that validation is likely something implemented somewhere inside your application